# Unable to start FIX Acceptor with Spring Boot Starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, fix-protocol

I am new to the FiX protocol. I cam across this spring boot starter in which i am trying to familiarise myself with it https://github.com/esanchezros/quickfixj-spring-boot-starter.

I have created 2 spring boot apps. At the moment is literally comprises of the main method and the main class is annotated with `@EnableQuickFixJClient` and `@EnableQuickFixJServer` respectively.

Although the client/initiator starts up fine, the server/acceptor application does not. I get a bean error:
`Consider defining a bean of type 'quickfix.Acceptor' in your configuration.` I know what the error means but when defining the bean, there's several different constructor args i need to pass in and I'm not sure what to pass in.

These are my configurations:

quickfixj-server.cfg:

```
[default]
FileStorePath=target/data/acceptor
ConnectionType=acceptor
SenderCompID=EXEC
TargetCompID=BANZAI
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=5
ReconnectInterval=5
FileLogPath=logs-server

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.1
SocketAcceptPort=9877
```

application.properties:

```
quickfixj.server.config=classpath:quickfixj-server.cfg
quickfixj.server.auto-startup=true 
quickfixj.server.force-disconnect=false 
quickfixj.server.phase=0
quickfixj.server.jmx-enabled=true 
quickfixj.server.concurrent.enabled=true 
quickfixj.server.message-store-factory=memory
quickfixj.server.log-factory=screen
```

Comment: When reading the info on the project page it doesn't sound like you need to call a constructor by yourself. Maybe you can double check with the doc on the project page if your config is still wrong?

Comment: Did you make sure your `quickfixj-server.cfg` can be found by the application?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a ready application with an example for the server and client (in one). You can modify it according to your needs and then develop it based on it.

https://github.com/esanchezros/quickfixj-spring-boot-starter-examples/tree/master/simple-client-and-server